# Plantilla en html5 : no aparecen los iconos

Tags: css, html5, css3

Acabo de descargar una plantilla en `HTML5`y me estoy dando cuenta que los iconos en `CSS` no aparecen en mi versión de la Web en local, pero si pilla los estilos, por ejemplo esto es un captura de la web original, donde descargue la plantilla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es un ejemplo de local:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A la hora de importar los `CSS` hago:

```
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/grid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/camera.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl-carousel.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script><!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <html class="lt-ie9">
      <div style="clear: both; text-align:center; position: relative;"><a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/.."><img src="images/ie8-panel/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg" border="0" height="42" width="820" alt="You are using an outdated browser. For a faster, safer browsing experience, upgrade for free today."></a></div>
    </html>
    <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="js/device.min.js"></script>
  </head>
```

para mostrarlos hace:

```
<div class="box">
 <div class="box_aside">
 <div class="icon2 fa-facebook"></div>
</div>
<div class="box_cnt__no-flow"><a href="#">Follow on facebook</a></div>
</div>
```

Que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: fa son iconos de fontawesom, donde estas cargando el css de fontawesom?

Comment: no tengo nada de fontawesom.  :(

Comment: arreglado gracias @Juan, por si alguien tiene el mismo problema , he descargado los fontwasen de su página oficial y los he cargado       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.css">

Comment: @JoCuTo Deberías añadirlo como respuesta para poder ayudar a futuros lectores.